# How to make Temperature vs. Energy graph representing a phase change?

Tags: thermodynamics

As we know that phase change graphs generally show a variation in the Temperature and time.The graph roughly looks like this. [image]

I guess that the shape of the curve will be the same. This is because the internal energy is rising as the temperature is rising (the average kinetic energy is increasing) and so we should get a somewhat linear relationship in this region. Next, the temperature remains constant while the potential energy is increasing.  I would like to know whether my guess is right, i.e. is the shape of the Temperature vs. Time graph and Temperature vs. Energy graph the same?

Comment: Enthalpy doesn't necessarily increase monotonically during phase transitions (e.g. melting of helium). Plus, enthalpy alone serves as a very poor order parameter for many phase transitions, including the water-ice transition (e.g. see [this paper](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/128/15/10.1063/1.2888999)).

Answer (score 2):

To draw the graph you have shown, you are assuming an addition of energy at all times. That would of course assumably be a *constant* addition of energy - that is, a constant energy addition *rate* (e.g. some fixed amount of Joules in the form of heat added to the system per second).

If that is the case, then on the Temperature/time graph each time increment (e.g. each second along the x-axis) corresponds to a certain and fixed amount of energy (heat) being added.

You could thus just as well replace the time-axis with an energy-axis. The curve would just be stretched or shrinked horizontally (depending on e.g. how many Joules added that correspond to one second passed) but will remain the same shape.

Comment: I just want to check my understanding: The shape of the graph will be the same except minor stretching or shrinking and the time axis is replaced with the Energy axis. This will give the new graph.

Comment: @ShreyAryan If the energy addition rate is constant, then yes. If this rate is e.g. 1000 Joules per second, then the Temperature/energy curve will be stretched to 1000 times wider (if we keep SI units in all cases).

Comment: You are very welcome